# How do i make <label> with <input> and its text stay active when i click on it with

Tags: html, css

Here is my little tryings in this, tried using checked and target but did'nt work out

```css
.label-test {
  font-size: 13;
  color: #6b7072;
}

.label-test:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="input-test" id="work">
<label for="work" class="label-test">all works</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the objective, but if it is to apply the `text-transform: capitalize` when the checkbox is checked, then the following CSS will do that:

```
input.input-test:checked + label.label-test {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

This works by changing the styling of the `label` after the `input` when the `input` is `checked`.

Here's a working snippet showing it in action:

```css
.label-test {
  font-size: 13;
  color: #6b7072;
}

.label-test:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

input.input-test:checked + label.label-test {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="input-test" id="work">
<label for="work" class="label-test">all works</label>
```